# Include failed step's error details in database mail for failed agent jobs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-agent, database-mail

I receive database notification mail whenever a job fails. Error message of the failed job (Step Id=0 in the Job History) is included in the mail;

> MESSAGES: The job failed.  The Job was invoked by User SomeUser.  The
>   last step to run was step 1 (FailingStep).

but not the step's failure message (Step Id > 0 in the Job History).
I also want to see the **step's message** so that I can identify the root cause directly from looking at the mail. For example, step 1's message in the above example.
Is it possible to include a job step's failure message within the alert mail?

Comment: Are the steps you execute TSQL ?

Comment: Yes. They mostly run stored procedures.

Comment: Ok then for the stored procedures, just build a try catch statement, and when your statement fails send an email with sp_send_dbmail with the error message. the others I would suggest putting them into stored procedures or if they are other types of manipulations (ssis powershell,...) sending a mail with their functionality

Comment: Hmm..I guess than there is no native way of doing it via job properties  without changing sp definition.